# Trouble with Wordpress multiple custom querystrings

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I'm working on adding multiple querystring and it doesn't seem to work. I've found some codes that seems to work for others but it might be that I'm missing something.

I want something like:

> http://mydomain.com/board/?getyear=2013&getsometext2=sometext

to

> http://mydomain.com/board/2013/sometext/

I then added the code below to the `functions.php` file. It doesn't seem to work as well as it should though.

This works. echoing the querystring gets both variable without a problem.

> http://mydomain.com/board/2013/sometext/

But this doesn't. I tested the querystring vis `isset()` but it seems like nothing is being set/get

> http://mydomain.com/board/2013/

```
function add_query_vars($vars) {
    $vars[] = "getyear";
    $vars[] = "getsometext2";
    return $vars;
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');

function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
    $aNewRules = array('board/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=board&getyear=$matches[1]&getsometext2=$matches[2]');
    $aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
    return $aRules;
}

add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I expected, I was missing a rewrite rule when the second parameter is not used. The answer is the code that worked for me:

```
function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
  'board/(.*)/(.*)/?' => 'index.php?pagename=board&getyear=$matches[1]&getsometext2=$matches[2]',
  'board/(.*)/?' => 'index.php?pagename=leaderboard&getyear=$matches[1]');
  $aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
  return $aRules;
}
```

Hope someone finds this useful.